# need help getting contents from an EditText and placing it in my url

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app where the user enters a url into the edit text field and my app takes him/her to that particular web page .

URL url = new URL("url_text.toString()");

i get an error as its not able to process the url .
what is the problem ?

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. the statement URL url = new URL(url_text.toString()); should not has a double quote.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the quotes.

```
URL url = new URL(url_text.toString());
```

otherwise you are trying to convert "url_text.toString()" to a URL rather than the content of url_text.

Comment: sorry the quotes was a typo . without the quotes also it does not work .

Answer (score 0):

Is url_text your EditText?

If it is then you need to call getText()

```
URL url = new URL(url_text.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . This will be of great help to me !

Comment: No problems, glad to help out.

Answer (score 0):

```
Button b;
       b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        ed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 String URL  = ed.getText().toString();
WebView web1 =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
                 web1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                 web1.loadUrl(URL);
}
        });
```

> ONE MORE THING I WANT TO REMIND IT THAT YOU NEED TO **PERMISSION OF INTERNET** FROM MANIFEST FILE